Why do my PolaroidNow+ Pictures Look faint
I just got the camera and tried some pictures on sunlight with stock defaults. The result was disappointing.
What am I missing? Should I set exposure to manual?

To me, this looks like general underexposure (top half), combined with fogging of the film due to undesired exposure from the bottom. Perhaps you have (inadvertently) exposed the cassette through the same slit through which photos are ejected.
